# MouseEvent.CLICK in transparent area

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movieClip that i want to get mouse click event on it,
it works fine but it doesn't fire this event when i click on transparent area.
is there any solution except to define a rectangle as hitArea?

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);

function onMouseClickEvent(event:Event) {

    trace("on clicked");
}
```

Comment: Yes, as far as I know you'll have to fill the area up with either a transparent rectangle or use a png image with transparency.

Comment: Actually, my understanding that a MovieClip registers clicks **anywhere** in its bounding box.  A Sprite will not register clicks in un-rendered areas within its bounding box, but a MovieClip will.  @Maryam, if Gurtej's suggestion doesn't work, can you post your full code?  EDIT - of course Gurtej's will work, because you're covering the area!  Can you post the code anyway, because a MovieClip should register regardless.

Comment: NEVERMIND!  My understanding of MovieClips is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you won't be able to click the transparent area, however, here is an alternate solution.

If you can monitor your mouse state with a global listener like:

```
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onStageClicked );
```

Then you can write another function that does a hit test against your display object:

```
public function mouseTest( someAsset:DisplayObject ):Boolean
{
    return someAsset.hitTestPoint( stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY );
}
```

Last from your `onStageClicked()` handler:

```
private function onStageClicked( e:Event ):void
{
    if ( mouseTest( mc ) )
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

That should suffice for the transparent area.